# Remove pager (dots) in new ion-slides ionic component

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to remove the pager in my ion-slides component. I tried all, but they still remain. How can I remove that? On the documentation nothing work. I spent 2 days in trying but nothing work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is:

```
options="{pagination: false}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the show-pager property to false.

```
  <ion-slide-box show-pager="false">
```

Comment: it isn't ion-slide-box but ion-slides because it won't support.

Comment: Those carousel dots are managed by ion slide box but not by individual slide

Comment: not slide, new ion-slides. The solution is options="{pagination: false}"

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property pager = "false"

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your .css file  if you are using  ion-slides

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    background:white!important;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 17px;   
    width: 17px;
    display: none;
}
```